# I want to select all those products name whose minimum available quantity is equal to zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have two database table `nrk_product` and `nrk_stock`.

I want to select all those products name from `nrk_product` table whose minimum available quantity is equal to zero.

I am writing following query which shows me those records whose available quantity is greater than zero, but I want reverse of this.

```
SELECT * FROM `nrk_product` AS `np`     
    LEFT JOIN `nrk_stock`  AS `ns`  
    ON `np`.`id` = `ns`.`product_id`        
    GROUP BY `np`.`id`
    HAVING (SUM(`ns`.`credit_quantity`) - SUM(`ns`.`debit_quantity`)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this :-

`=0`
or 
`< 0`

```
SELECT nrk_product FROM nrk_product AS np
LEFT JOIN nrk_stock AS ns
ON np.id = ns.product_id
GROUP BY np.id HAVING (SUM(ns.credit_quantity) - SUM(ns.debit_quantity)) = 0
```

Comment: = 0 or < 0 give me an empty result because of some products stock entries are not added in `nrk_stock ` table.

Comment: can you explain more what you want ?

Comment: Sir, I have two database table named - nrk_product and nrk_stock.

Comment: can you share you table structure and what result you want ??

Comment: Sir, I have two database table named - nrk_product and nrk_stock. nrk_product table contains id of nrk_product table and product_name. nrk_stock stock table contains columns like itself id, product_id, product credit_quantity and debit_quantity. nrk_stock table is used to credit and debit the product stock. Now I want to show such product those product stock is less than one or equal to zero. here is one situation where product may or may not be added in nrk_stock table.

Comment: Yes I have try all above queries but if I am use = 0 or < 0 it's return me an empty result but I use > 0 the it return me those product whose quantity is greater than one.

Comment: SELECT nrk_product FROM nrk_product AS np
LEFT JOIN nrk_stock AS ns
ON np.id = ns.product_id
GROUP BY np.id HAVING (SUM(ns.credit_quantity) - SUM(IFNULL(ns.debit_quantity,0)) <= 0

Comment: please try this query @tanisha

Comment: Sir, It's give me #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2 error

Comment: SELECT nrk_product FROM nrk_product AS np LEFT JOIN nrk_stock AS ns ON np.id = ns.product_id GROUP BY np.id HAVING (SUM(ns.credit_quantity) - SUM(IFNULL(ns.debit_quantity,0))) <= 0

Comment: sorry my mistake plz check again this query :(

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the reverse of it than just replace greater than(>) with less than equal to(<=)

```
SELECT * FROM `nrk_product` AS `np`     
    LEFT JOIN `nrk_stock`  AS `ns`  
    ON `np`.`id` = `ns`.`product_id`        
    GROUP BY `np`.`id`
    HAVING (SUM(`ns`.`credit_quantity`) - SUM(`ns`.`debit_quantity`)) <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `nrk_product` AS `np`     
    LEFT JOIN `nrk_stock`  AS `ns`  
    ON `np`.`id` = `ns`.`product_id`        
    GROUP BY `np`.`id`
    HAVING (SUM(`ns`.`credit_quantity`) - SUM(`ns`.`debit_quantity`)) < 1
```